# Logback Format for JSON

Tags: java, json, logging, logback

Is there a way to suggest a format for Logback to print JSON in a pretty way.

It is very annoying to read json as a single line and I did not know if there was a way to use regex to specify:

example this is default:

```
2016-04-28 17:59:26 DEBUG [FILE.java:126] {"TemplateInterpretation" : { "InterpretationLabel" : "T" , "InterpretationConfidence" : 1.0}}
```

What I would rather have is:

```
2016-04-28 17:59:26 DEBUG [FILE.java:126] {
    "TemplateInterpretation" : {
        "InterpretationLabel" : "T" ,
        "InterpretationConfidence" : 1.0
    }
}
```

I am using Logback but through slf4j

I am also trying to pretty print Mongodb objects with come with a toString method which does this:

```
/**
 * Returns a JSON serialization of this object
 * @return JSON serialization
 */    
@Override
public String toString(){
    return JSON.serialize( this );
}
```

I would rather not have to create my own version of the mongo serializer just to add new lines...

Comment: Does logback support serializing JSON? Are you sure you aren't sending JSON yourself? Just pretty print it before logging it.

Comment: I am using mongodb and they return a string to me that is not pretty print formatted so I can't really manually pretty print it myself without making a json to mongodb library which is overkill in my opinion

Comment: Ok. Logback can't do this out of the box. It just takes what you provide and calls `toString` on it. You need to pre-format it, which requires JSON parsing.

Comment: Have you tried logstash-logback-encoder?